# Rails not able to specify foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to join two tables using [joins](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins). But because of [Active Record referential integrity](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity), I'm not able to join the tables. (Read further for proper understanding)

I have models as follows:

1. Teams
2. Alerts
3. Subscriptions

Every team will subscribe to some types of alerts. `Subscriptions` table have 2 foreign keys i.e. `team_id` and `kind_id` which references to Primary Keys of the tables `Teams` and `Alerts`, respectively.

I have created a migration where I have added:

```
add_foreign_key :subscriptions, :teams, column: :team_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
add_foreign_key :subscriptions, :alerts, column: :kind_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

and ran migrations.

Also, I have specified associations in respective classes.

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :alert, :foreign_key => 'kind_id'
  belongs_to :team

  validates :team_id, uniqueness: { scope: :kind_id }
end
```

But when I try to join **`Alert.joins(:subscription)`** the query rails forms is:

```
SELECT `alerts`.* FROM `alerts` INNER JOIN `subscriptions` ON `subscriptions`.`alert_id` = `alerts`.`id`
```

Where as what it should have been is:

```
SELECT `alerts`.* FROM `alerts` INNER JOIN `subscriptions` ON `subscriptions`.`kind_id` = `alerts`.`id`
```

(The difference is the column name in subscriptions table {it should be `kind_id` instead of `alert_id`})

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A workaround would be `Alert.joins("INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.kind_id = alerts.id")`. But I don't want to put raw SQL queries in my code.

Comment: _But I don't want to put raw SQL queries in my code_ why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the foreign key on the corresponding `has_many` relation as well in the `Alert` model. Currently, you've specified the foreign key conditions on the `Subscription` model. `Subscription.joins(:alerts)` would work now. However, the join mentioned in the question is from the `Alert` end, which is why it isn't working as expected since we haven't told the `Alert` model to check for a different foreign key.

This can be done as follows:

```
class Alert < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions, foreign_key: :kind_id
end
```

Comment: Edited the model name @SebastianPalma. Thanks!